# AWS RDS is showing very high wait/synch/mutex/sql/ values and EXPLAIN statements in performance insights

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I'm running a CRON script which checks the database for work and executes anything that needs to be done.  It does this across ~500 customers per minute, but we are using AWS RDS with a 16 vCPU machine which, until recently, has been plentiful to keep it happy (normally plugging along under 20%).

This weekend we updated customers to the latest version of the code and implemented some tooling, and since then we've started seeing these huge waits:
[image]

Further I'm seeing that about half of our busiest queries are EXPLAIN statements, somewhere illustrated here:
[image]

Nowhere in our code base is an "EXPLAIN" performed (though we are using AWS RDS performance insights, ProxySQL and New Relic for monitoring).  I did notice that in the past week our number of DB connections was previously baselined around 10 and is now closer to 90.
[image]

**Any ideas on where I should be digging to find the cause of these waits and explain statements?**  And if they could justify the large number of open connections?

Comment: Do `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see who is logging in.  I _suspect_ that some of the changes are due to monitoring.  If everyone is logging in as "root", fix that so that you can figure out who's who.  Meanwhile, turn on the slowlog to get a different view into the issues.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: Do you use the `LOCK TABLES` sql command?  (If so, Don't!)

Comment: In that same link, go to the part about tuning -- there is some strangeness in the table-cache that needs investigating.

Comment: Re EXPLAINs -- are subqueries involved?  Let's see the full text of some of them, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thank you, I got the answer from AWS just an hour before your comments.  Personally my issue was `table_open_cache` limit defaults to 20000 in MySQL and I was crossing that threshold.

Comment: Hmmm...  I don't see how that is relevant.  But glad that they solved it.

Comment: I'm not the person on my team who spoke to AWS, but in order to document this for those who follow: they said because the number of open tables was larger than the cache it was causing the DB to lock and queue up requests.

Comment: That sounds "wrong".  A "cache" bumps items out of the cache to make room.  Did they say which STATUS and VARIABLES they were looking at?  (That will help me tie to stuff I know more about.)

Comment: Explain statements are probably coming from NewRelic. NewRelic client for Rails, at least, does that to slow queries. You can tune what's the "slow" threshold.